# Clojure fibonacci

Tags: clojure

```
#(take %
  (map first
    (iterate (fn [[i1 i2]]
                 [i2 (+ i1 i2)])
             [1 1])))
```

This is a function to generate fib seq in clojure.
I don't understand this part:

```
(fn [[i1 i2]]
          [i2 (+ i1 i2)])
          [1 1])
```

from [i1 i2] to [i2 (+ i1 i2)].
how does make this sequence keep growing? seems to me it is always 2 elements.
need help. thanks!

Comment: While this question is very closely related to that question I think it's not quite duplicate because it's more specific.

Comment: It looks confusing due to bad indentation.  It looks like the body of the inner function and the second argument of `iterate` are at the same level.

Comment: fixed the formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the function

```
(fn [[i1 i2]]
  [i2 (+ i1 i2)])
```

takes in one step of the sequence and produces the next step in the process. So each call produces one more step in the sequence. This is an intermediate solution where every step has two elements in it. The first element is the answer thus far, and the second one provides enough context to produce the next step. so the output would look like:

```
user> (take 5  
            (iterate (fn [[i1 i2]]
                         [i2 (+ i1 i2)])
                     [1 1]))
([1 1] [1 2] [2 3] [3 5] [5 8])
```

Then a later stage takes this entire sequence and removes the extra information leaving only the answers from each step.

```
user> (map first
           (take 5  
                 (iterate (fn [[i1 i2]]
                            [i2 (+ i1 i2)])
                          [1 1])))
(1 1 2 3 5)
```

This is a great application of breaking a problem down into seperable parts and then composing these parts to form the final answer.

Answer (score 1):

The function passed to `iterate` is

```
(fn [[i1 i2]]
    [i2 (+ i1 i2)])
```

All the function does is generate the next term in the sequence given a previous one (using pattern-matching to assign the names i1 and i2 to the members of the passed-in vector).

`iterate` takes two arguments, the function that generates the next term in the sequence, and the starting value for the sequence. The function `iterate` is in charge of generating the lazy sequence.

For an easier example (without the pattern-matching), you could generate a lazy sequence of positive integers with

```
(iterate inc 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are quite right. The function ...

```
(fn [[i1 i2]] [i2 (+ i1 i2)])
```

... does produce one pair of numbers from another. For example,

```
((fn [[i1 i2]] [i2 (+ i1 i2)]) [6 19])

; [19 25]
```

Its `iterate` that produces the sequence, by repeatedly applying the function. This yields a sequence of pairs:

```
(iterate (fn [[i1 i2]] [i2 (+' i1 i2)]) [1 1])

;([1 1] [1 2] [2 3] [3 5] [5 8] [8 13] [13 21] ...)
```

The first or the second elements of these pairs form a Fibonacci sequence,
depending where you want to start. To get the former, we just wrap the above in `(map first ...)`:

```
(map first (iterate (fn [[i1 i2]] [i2 (+' i1 i2)]) [1 1]))

;(1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 ...)
```

If you're familiar with the `->>` threading macro, you might find it easier to read as

```
(->> [1 1]
     (iterate (fn [[i1 i2]] [i2 (+ i1 i2)]))
     (map first))

;(1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 ...)
```